# Remove end of line characters from Java string

Tags: java, string, end-of-line

I have string like this

```
"hello
java
book"
```

I want remove `\r` and `\n` from `String(hello\r\njava\r\nbook)`. I want the result to be `"hellojavabook"`. How can I do this?

Comment: StringUtils.chomp()

Answer (score 142):

Regex with replaceAll.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv) 
    {
        String str;

        str = "hello\r\njava\r\nbook";
        str = str.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

If you only want to remove \r\n when they are pairs (the above code removes either \r or \n) do this instead:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
```

Comment: I would recommend you used `System.getProperty("line.separator");`, instead of hardcoded line breakers. Each OS has its own line separator.

Comment: @GGrec sometimes the text String / File was not made by the same OS. So `System.getProperty("line.separator");` won't work in these cases. But yes, if you can trust the same-OS origin, it is better to use the system property.

Comment: How would you use the value returned for `line.separator`? I tried passing `"\\" + lineSeparator` in the regex and it did not work

Comment: otherwise I think str = srt.trim() would also works fine

Answer (score 19):

```
public static void main(final String[] argv) 
{
    String str;

    str = "hello\r\n\tjava\r\nbook";
    str = str.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", "");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

It would be useful to add the tabulation in regex too.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to avoid the regex, or must target an earlier JVM, String.replace() will do:

```
str=str.replace("\r","").replace("\n","");
```

And to remove a CRLF pair:

```
str=str.replace("\r\n","");
```

The latter is more efficient than building a regex to do the same thing.  But I think the former will be faster as a regex since the string is only parsed once.

Answer (score 5):

Given a String str:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\r","")
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\n","")
```

Comment: This is an unnecessarily inefficient way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can either directly pass line terminator e.g. \n, if you know the line terminator in Windows, Mac or UNIX. Alternatively you can use following code to replace line breaks in either of three major operating system.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
```

Above code line will replace line breaks with space in Mac, Windows and Linux.
Also you can use line-separator. It will work for all OS. Below is the code snippet for line-separator.

```
String lineSeparator=System.lineSeparator();
String newString=yourString.replace(lineSeparator, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [replaceAll](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to replace any occurence of \n or \r with the empty String?

Answer (score 2):

```
static byte[] discardWhitespace(byte[] data) {
    byte groomedData[] = new byte[data.length];
    int bytesCopied = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        switch (data[i]) {
            case (byte) '\n' :
            case (byte) '\r' :
                break;
            default:
                groomedData[bytesCopied++] = data[i];
        }
    }

    byte packedData[] = new byte[bytesCopied];

    System.arraycopy(groomedData, 0, packedData, 0, bytesCopied);

    return packedData;
}
```

Code found on commons-codec project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unescapeJava` from `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils` like below

```
str = "hello\r\njava\r\nbook";
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
```

Comment: This is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I went with `\\s+` and it removed `\r` and `\n` chars for me.

> `\s+` will match one or more whitespace characters

```java
final String stringWithWhitespaceChars = "Bart\n\r";
final String stringWithoutEscapeChars = stringWithEscapeChars.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Refer to [Regex expressions in Java, \\s vs. \\s+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625629/regex-expressions-in-java-s-vs-s) for in detail informations.

Answer (score 0):

Hey we can also use this regex solution.

```
String chomp = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(sentence.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]"," "));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below code. It worked for me.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\r", "");
str = str.replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593671/remove-end-of-line-characters-from-java-string/68209032#comment405530_593681

Answer (score -7):

Did you try

```
string.trim();
```

This is meant to trim all leading and leaning while spaces in the string. Hope this helps.

Edit: (I was not explicit enough)

So, when you string.split(), you will have a string[] - for each of the strings in the array, do a string.trim() and then append it.

```
String[] tokens = yourString.split(" ");
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
for (String token : tokens)
{
  buff.append(token.trim());
}
```

Use stringBuffer/Builder instead of appending in the same string.

Comment: What is the problem here? Trim takes away everything and gives back just the string?

Comment: Trim removes leading/trailing whitespace.  Line breaks in the middle of a string will not be removed.