# Remove end of line characters from end of Java String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string which I'd like to remove the end of line characters from the very end of the string only using Java

```
"foo\r\nbar\r\nhello\r\nworld\r\n"
```

which I'd like to become

```
"foo\r\nbar\r\nhello\r\nworld"
```

(This question is similar to, but not the same as question [593671](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593671))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`s = s.replaceAll("[\r\n]+$", "");`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). This trims the `\r` and `\n` characters at the end of the string

The regex is explained as follows:

- `[\r\n]` is a character class containing `\r` and `\n`
- `+` is one-or-more repetition of
- `$` is the end-of-string anchor

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

---

#### Related topics

You can also use [`String.trim()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to trim *any* whitespace characters from the *beginning* and *end* of the string:

```
s = s.trim();
```

If you need to check if a `String` contains nothing but whitespace characters, you can check if it [`isEmpty()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) after `trim()`:

```
if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
   //...
}
```

Alternatively you can also see if it [`matches("\\s*")`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), i.e. zero-or-more of whitespace characters. Note that in Java, the regex `matches` tries to match the *whole* string. In flavors that can match a substring, you need to anchor the pattern, so it's `^\s*$`.

#### Related questions

- [regex, check if a line is blank or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012788/regex-check-if-a-line-is-blank-or-not/)
- [how to replace 2 or more spaces with single space in string and delete leading spaces only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932392/java-how-to-replace-2-or-more-spaces-with-single-space-in-string-and-delete-leadi/)

Comment: and the second option will leave any leading whitespace?

Comment: `trim()` will also remove leading whitespace, that's not what is being asked.

Comment: @sprocket: which second option are you talking about? The solution in this reply will leave leading whitespace intact.

Comment: @polygenelubricants does this deal with (as Jesper asked in a comment on another answer) the cases where a string ends with "\n\r" instead of "\r\n", or only "\n" without "\r"?

Comment: @sprocketonline: yes, character class is a set, i.e. unordered. `[ab]` is the same as `[ba]`, a character class matching `a` or `b`. Order only matters when you're defining a range, i.e. `[0-9]`, not `[9-0]`. `[ab]` is not the same as `ab`.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't [String.trim](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) do the trick here?

i.e you'd call the method `.trim()` on your string and it should return a copy of that string minus any leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: He explicitly said: "... from the very end of the string only", so he doesn't want to remove leading whitespace.

Comment: Yeah I know.  Still, the example string didn't have any leading whitespace so I thought it was worth a shot...

Answer (score 2):

The Apache Commons Lang [`StringUtils.stripEnd(String str, String stripChars)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#stripEnd(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) will do the trick; e.g.

```
    String trimmed = StringUtils.stripEnd(someString, "\n\r");
```

If you want to remove *all* whitespace at the end of the String:

```
    String trimmed = StringUtils.stripEnd(someString, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, everyone gave some way to do it with regex, so I'll give a fastest way possible instead:

```
public String replace(String val) {
    for (int i=val.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
        char c = val.charAt(i);
        if (c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
            return val.substring(0, i+1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Benchmark says it operates ~45 times faster than regexp solutions.

Comment: I think you can do faster without `toCharArray()` using `charAt` instead.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Indeed. Checked java source and you are right. Somehow I thought that toCharArray just returns the inner value of string. But after looking at the sources of java I see it copies the array to a new one. Gonna change my answer too.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Google's [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)in your project (if not, you arguably should!) you'd do this with a [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
String result = CharMatcher.any("\r\n").trimTrailingFrom(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "foo\r\nbar\r\nhello\r\nworld\r\n";
String result = text.replaceAll("[\r\n]+$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"foo\r\nbar\r\nhello\r\nworld\r\n".replaceAll("\\s+$", "")
or
"foo\r\nbar\r\nhello\r\nworld\r\n".replaceAll("[\r\n]+$", "")
```