# string ends with '\n' what is the most efficient way to manipulate?

Tags: java, android, string

it happens that the user click on enter where i dont want to include it as a part of my input the string can end with 3 times \n so just replacing one wont do the job 
my solution was ;

```
String values[] = string_Ends_With_Back_Slash_N.split("\n"); 
String String_without_Back_Slash_N =new String (values [0]);
//or just to point there without the new but i want later to dump the garbage.
```

or at least to dump values to the gc now ....

so two q :

1. is there more efficent way?..
2. who do i call the compiler (java on android ...)

Comment: can you use StringUtils in Android? There are some handy functions there for dealing with Strings.
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100585/remove-end-of-line-characters-from-end-of-java-string

Comment: I'd also encourage you to get used to the language's conventions - although it has nothing to do with the question per se, your variables should conventionally in lower camel case, e.g. `String stringWithoutBackSlashN`.  I actually found it noticably harder to read your code because you're violating the naming conventions.

Comment: andrzej you right i started writing camel case but it appeared here ugley therefore i changed it to the one who's showen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String String_without_Back_Slash_N = string_Ends_With_Back_Slash_N.trim()
```

Comment: i have tried ... :)
it didnt delete the /n ...
in java on eclipse... in c# i think it does work i don't have a compiler but this is a nuce thing if someone can check

Comment: @yoav.str I checked and it worked. It is not `/n` - it is `\n`

Answer (score 5):

Try [`String.trim()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

This methods removes all characters from the ends of the String, which have an ascii code smaller than the space (interval, 32). This includes `\n` (10).

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "test\n\n\n";
s.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Comment: the return type is the one i look for
String temp = s.replaceAll("\n", "");

but still my question is there more efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

replace all `\n` (and maybe `\r`) with `""`

Comment: yes but the reason i ask for guidelines is that i want to improve efficiency therefore your answer doesnt help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since strings are immutable there is no need to create a new string. If you dump the "garbage" the garbage collector will recognize that the first element in the array is still referenced and not throw it away. The rest will be disposed of.