# Java Writing in a File

Tags: java, file

I am writing in a file and I want it to output into a csv file this way:

```
Group  Members  
 1     Name1  
       Name2  
       Name3
```

code:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(csv);
BufferedWriter pw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
pw.write("Group,");
pw.write("Members");
pw.newline();
String mem=some_method();
pw.write("1,");
pw.write(mem);
pw.newLine();
```

My String mem has '\n' every after the names and so when it writes in the file, '\n' is read then writes into the next line. How can i achieve the above output without modifying the some_method()?

Comment: See also: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try as below,

```
String mem=some_method();
mem = mem.replace("\n", "");
```

Instead of \n you can also use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` which gives you platform independent line separator.

```
mem = mem.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to strip the new line characters in mem.

Check out
[Remove end of line characters from Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593671/remove-end-of-line-characters-from-java-string)

Put simply you can add the line `mem = mem.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");`

Comment: If i'll remove them, then the names would not display in next lines within the cell.

Comment: If you want to keep the new line characters but have it appear as one cell then you just have to enclose the element in double quotes ("). e.g. pw.write("\"" + mem + "\"");

Comment: Just bear in mind you need to make sure that mem doesn't contain double quotes or they are at least escaped. e.g. mem = mem.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");

Comment: this works, pw.write("\"" + mem + "\""); thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you combine the Group and Member together in one write method like:

```
pw.write("Group \t\t Members");
```

and do the same with the other contents. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not follow the format.