# How to replace new lines

Tags: java, string

Unfortunately, I'm having some difficulty replacing new lines.

```
public class Example {

    static String s = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\n" +
        "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\n" +
        "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\n" +
        "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\n" +
        "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\n" +
        "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\n" +
        "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\n" +
        "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\n" +
        "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\n" +
        "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\n" +
        "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\n" +
        "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\n" +
        "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\n" +
        "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\n" +
        "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\n" +
        "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\n" +
        "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\n" +
        "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\n" +
        "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\n" +
        "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450".replaceAll("\\n", "");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I would like to remove all occurrences of `\n` from String `s`.  I tried looking up the answer on StackOverflow, but every post seems to have a different answer (and they are all complicated and hard to remember).

Is there a simple way of doing this?

---

I have also tried

```
replaceAll("\n", "")
replaceAll("\\\\n", "")
replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "")
replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "")
```

Comment: try this one: `replace("\n", "");`

Comment: That doesn't work, either :(

Comment: I know the duplicate question is not identical, but the answer to this question is included in the answer to that one.

Comment: @Keppil I disagree with that duplicate. Not the same question.. (and that's what matters). So I've reopened.

Comment: @Keppil, yes, comment editted.

Comment: @Duncan: Fine, I guess. Then please close it as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593671/remove-end-of-line-characters-from-java-string instead.

Comment: Actually, the `\\n` is correct, but it is not working in defining the string. Try removing it and printing `s.replaceAll("\\n","")`

Comment: @Keppil why are you so intent on closing my question? I tried the solution in your post... **it didn't work**.

Comment: @ktm5124: It's nothing personal. If a question has already been asked and answered, it should be closed to reduce noise for future visitors.

Comment: Look at @Pshemo answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"hello" + "world".replace("o","")
```

is same as

```
"hello" + ("world".replaceAll("o",""))
```

So `replaceAll` will affect only last part of your string, which in your case is

```
"71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450".replaceAll("\\n", "").
```

To solve this problem use parenthesis to first concatenate all string parts, and then call replace on resulting string.

```
static String s = (
        "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\n" +
        "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\n" +
        "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\n" +
        "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\n" +
        "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\n" +
        "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\n" +
        "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\n" +
        "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\n" +
        "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\n" +
        "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\n" +
        "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\n" +
        "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\n" +
        "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\n" +
        "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\n" +
        "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\n" +
        "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\n" +
        "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\n" +
        "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\n" +
        "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\n" +
        "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
    ).replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

---

But in situation where we are not dealing with initializing field, I would prefer splitting this "one-liner" into more steps which will be more readable and you will avoid errors like one from your question:

```
//concatenation
String s =  "....."
           +"....."
           :
           +".....";

//modification
s = s.replaceAll("\\n","");
```

Comment: @yoseph1998 It will. Regex engine in Java allows us to write `\n` as `"\\n"`. To create ``\`` literal in regex engine we would need to write it as `"\\\\"` string. `"\\"` is regex metacharacter and can be used to produce `\n` which will represent line break.

Comment: my bad, i'll delete the comment

Comment: Nice catch. Even better would be to use `replace` though, since you are not using a regex.

Comment: @Keppil `replace` also uses regex engine, but it just adds escaping mechanisms for us. It would be different story if we would use `replace(char, char)` which really doesn't use regex because it is simple iteration.

Comment: Ah, indeed it does. Then I have no objections. :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, when you are doing

```
static String s = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\n" +
        "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\n" +
        "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\n" +
        "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\n" +
        "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\n" +
        "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\n" +
        "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\n" +
        "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\n" +
        "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\n" +
        "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\n" +
        "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\n" +
        "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\n" +
        "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\n" +
        "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\n" +
        "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\n" +
        "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\n" +
        "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\n" +
        "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\n" +
        "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\n" +
        "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450".replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

you are only replacing the last concatenation of that string (Note: which has no `"\n"`).

what you need to do is get rid of that `replaceAll` in your string declaration, and in your main method do `s = s.replaceAll("\n", "");` like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    s = s.replaceAll("\n", "");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Tested and works :D
Hope this was helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

You could split and join the string before printing it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(String.join("", s.split("\n")));
}
```