# Replace \ and newline replace in java

Tags: java, replaceall

I am writing code to detect bad keywords in a file. Here are the steps that I follow:

1. Tokenize using StreamTokenizer
2. Use pattern matcher to find the matches

   ```
   while(streamTokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
               if(streamTokenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
                   String token = streamTokenizer.sval.trim().replaceAll("\\\\n", "")
                   final Matcher matcher = badKeywordPattern.matcher(token)
                   if(matcher.find()) { // bad tokens found
                        return true;
                   }
               }
   }
   ```

`String token = streamTokenizer.sval.trim().replaceAll("\\\\n", "")` is done to match token spanning multiple lines with `\`. Example:

`bad\
token`

However the replace is not working. Any suggestions? Any other ways to do this?

Comment: have tried this `String token = streamTokenizer.sval.trim().replaceAll("\\"+"\n", "")`

Comment: This won't work. You won't get he entire multi line token in one piece. You have to cincatenate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove all `\` placed at end of the line, along with line separator you could use `replaceAll("\\\\\\R","")`.

- To represent `\` in regex (which is what `replaceAll` uses) we need to escape it with another `\`, which leaves us with `\\`. But since `\` is also special in String literals we need to escape each of them again with another backslash which leaves us with `"\\\\"`
- Since Java 8 we can use `\R` (which needs to be written as `"\\R"` since `\` requires escaping) to represent line separators like `\r` `\n` or `\r\n` pair.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you do not want to use regex (which is what `String.replaceAll` does), just do literal string replacement with [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), and use one fewer backslash:

```
String token = streamTokenizer.sval.trim().replace("\\\n", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Pshemo [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43599405/3025545), which shows you how `\` & `\n` presented in regex, and as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12085359/3025545). You could do it like this:

```
String[] tkns = streamTokenizer.sval.trim().split("\\\\\\R"); // yourString = "bad\\\ntaken"
StringBuffer token= new StringBuffer();
for (String tkn : tkns)
{
    token.append(tkn);
    //System.out.println(tkn);
}
//final Matcher matcher = badKeywordPattern.matcher(token)
```