# Java, how could we trim carriage return and line break?

Tags: java, string, debugging, if-statement, web

**Hello**:

I am developing a web app using Java and beans.

I am trying to do a converter which checks if a message which the user introduces using a textarea is less than 5 characters long.

The difficulty is that event if the text area is empty it stills having /r/n and some spaces after it.

I have alreaady tried:

```
@Stateless
public class ComentarioNota {

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
    public String convierteComentarioNota(String evaluacion, String comentario) {
        if (evaluacion.trim().equals("Apto") && comentario != null && comentario.length() > 5) {
            return "Apto";
        } else {
            return "No Apto";
        }
    }
}
```

And when debbugging we can see the comment value in the comentario parameter:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/19931443/1951298

Comment: Trim comentario: `comentario.trim()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove end of line characters from Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593671/remove-end-of-line-characters-from-java-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the linebreaks before the trim.
[How to remove line breaks from a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java)

[How to remove newlines from beginning and end of a string (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454330/how-to-remove-newlines-from-beginning-and-end-of-a-string-java)

```
text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```