# Remove plaintext \n from string in Java

Tags: java

I am using the wikimedia api to get content from wikipedia pages. The api returns a lot of "\n" as plain text. I want to remove them from a string

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\n", "");
s = s.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Neither of these work, any ideas?

Comment: Give us an example of the source text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove line breaks from a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove end of line characters from Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593671/remove-end-of-line-characters-from-java-string)

Answer (score 2):

When your String contains a plaintext `\n` it is actually a `\\n` otherwise it would be displayed as a linebreak, which is why I found `s = s.replaceAll("\\\\n","")` to be working for me. An example snippet:

```
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "Hello\\nHello";
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.replaceAll("\\\\n","");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Remember that replaceAll takes a Regex: Since you want to replace 2 /s you have to escape both of them, therefore`////`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please to use below code format:

s= s.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
s = s.replace("\n", "");
```

but, the newline character can be different among the environments. 
So, you can use this

```
s = s.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
```